# FactoryGirl not accepting property overrides

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot

I am sure this is a trivial typo but I don't see it. This code is after slashing down to the minimum and I still see this syntax error. Forgive my stupidity, as I know I will feel once you show me what I am not seeing!

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    name "a name"
  end
end

@goodguy = FactoryGirl.create (:user, {:name => "a"})
```

is giving me:

```
/Users/pitosalas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@repeatsurvey/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:780:in `load': /Volumes/MonsterHD/mydev/repsurv/spec/models/access_control_spec.rb:29: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting ')' (SyntaxError)
      @goodguy = FactoryGirl.create (:user, {:name => "a"})
                                           ^
/Volumes/MonsterHD/mydev/repsurv/spec/models/access_control_spec.rb:29: syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting keyword_end
      @goodguy = FactoryGirl.create (:user, {:name => "a"})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get rid of the space after `create`

```
@goodguy = FactoryGirl.create(:user, {:name => "a"})
```

For example

```
[3] pry(main)> FactoryGirl.create (:staff_user, {:first_name => "ben"})
SyntaxError: unexpected ',', expecting ')'
FactoryGirl.build (:staff_user, {:first_name => "ben"})
                               ^
[3] pry(main)> FactoryGirl.create(:staff_user, {:first_name => "ben"})
=> #<User::Staff id: 1, ...
```

---

To explain, when you put a space after the method name, everything in the `(...)` is treated argument #1 for your method invocation An alternative that works **with** the space is to leave out the parens.

```
@goodguy = FactoryGirl.create :user, {:name => "a"}
```

You get an error because Ruby is trying to evaluate `(:user, {:name => "a"})` as an expression which of course makes no sense on it's own.

```
[7] pry(main)> (:user, {:name => "a"})
SyntaxError: unexpected ',', expecting ')'
(:user, {:name => "a"})
       ^
```

Comment: Yikes. Thanks! Why? I never noticed that! I thought it was just formatting etiquette not actual wrong syntax.

Comment: Never knew that thanks! Hmmm. Can you explain why ruby comes up with that confusing error message?

Comment: There's not really anything confusing about it. `(:user, {:name => "a"})` is a bad expression in Ruby; it's syntactically **invalid** to have a comma after `:user` in *your* "expression". Ruby assumes by the comma you're trying to end the expression started with the open paren `(` which is why it's instead looking for the close paren `)` and yelling when it finds something else (the comma).

Comment: Thanks. I guess something was confused, either the message or me :) But basically I understand now that when there's a space after a method name, then () is interpreted as a single parenthesized expression, in which commas are not permitted.